# Change Variable values in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to change some variables in different methos in Flutter, but the value isn't changed.

An example is something like:

```
enum UserPlaceStatusType { NONE, GOING, THERE, OUT, CANCELLED }

class PlaceCardState extends State<PlaceCard> {
    UserPlaceStatusType _isOtherPlaceActive = UserPlaceStatusType.NONE;

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: this._getBody(),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: this._getBottomNavigationBar()));
    }

    List<Widget> _getBody() {
        return [
            Expanded(child: Text('test'), flex: 3),
            Expanded(child: Text('test'), flex: 6),
            Expanded(child: this._getActionsMenu(), flex: 1)
        ];
    }

    Widget _getActionsMenu() {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          color: Colors.grey[400],
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return new Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: new Icon(Icons.train),
                        title: new Text(Utility.format(
                            Language.of(context).takePlace, [_place.title])),
                        onTap: () {
                          showUserStatusDialog<DialogActions>(
                              context: context,
                              //It opens a simple dialog
                              child: this._getCurrentUserPlaceStatus());
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          },
        ));
    }

    Widget _getCurrentUserPlaceStatus() {
    return new GraphqlProvider(
        client: new ValueNotifier(
          Client(endPoint: 'GraphQLUrl', cache: new InMemoryCache()),
        ),
        child: new Query(
          'The GraphQL Query',
          variables: {},
          builder: ({
            bool loading,
            var data,
            var error,
          }) {
            if (data != null && data['getCurrentUserPlaceStatus'] != null) {
              this._isOtherPlaceActive = UserPlaceStatusType.THERE;
              Navigator.pop(context, DialogActions.cancel);
              return Container();
            } else {
              this._isOtherPlaceActive = UserPlaceStatusType.GOING;
              Navigator.pop(context, DialogActions.cancel);
              return Container();
            }
          },
        ));
    }

    void showUserStatusDialog<T>({BuildContext context, Widget child}) async {
        //here there is a validation but the variable value is the initial one, I mean NONE
        if (this._isOtherPlaceActive == UserPlaceStatusType.GOING) {
            //Cod to do    
            return;
        }

        showDialog<T>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => child,
        ).then<void>((T value) {
        if (value != null) {
            this._isOtherPlaceActive = UserPlaceStatusType.NONE;
            Navigator.pop(context);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

I changed the variable value through some methods, but when I need to apply the validation, that's the initial value, it isn't changed, and I could not apply SetState method cuz it breaks the modal and throws an exception.

I will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: What variable changes are not working? What error do you get when you use `setState()`?

Comment: The change in this variable _isOtherPlaceActive, that's not reflected, it always have the initial value, and the issue with setState is something regarding to animation I guess, it couldn't rebuild when the simple dialog is taking action, and also when the GraphQL Provider is taking place

Comment: It indicates that the issue is in AnimationController
And also it says: Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Comment: The code you posted does not include any calls to setState... At any rate, you can't call it during the build process, it is usually done in response to a user action. `onTap: () => setState(() => doSomething()),`.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is when the else case is applied in this in if (data != null && data['getCurrentUserPlaceStatus'] != null) 
When this code takes place:
this._isOtherPlaceActive = UserPlaceStatusType.GOING;
              Navigator.pop(context, DialogActions.cancel);
              return Container();

It makes that issue when showUserStatusDialog takes place, that happens when the showDialog takes process, if the variable be changed, that issue will not happen, that issue doesn't stop the app, but that's an exception in console.

Answer (score 0):

The method `setState()` can't be called inside a widget directly. I'm curious with your use of [`GrapQLProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/graphql_flutter/latest/graphql_flutter/GraphQLProvider-class.html) since it returns an empty `Container()` widget just to check the status of the data.

While I'm unfamiliar with the use of [GraphQL](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql), if the `client` that you're using inherits either a `Stream` or `Future`, it can be used to listen when the query is done.

Here's some snippets as demo. Let `_testFuture()` as the sample for a Future callback.

```dart
Future _testFuture() async{
  return null;
}
```

Future can be listened to inside a Widget. When the request finishes, we have the opportunity to call `setState()`.

```dart
_testFuture().then((value) {
  // Check for values here
  setState(() {
    // Update values
  });
});
```

Or if the request is set in a `Stream`, it's also possible to listen for Stream changes inside a Widget.

```dart
_streamController.add(_testFuture());
  _streamController.stream.listen((event) {
  // Check for values here
  setState(() {
     // Update values
  });
});
```

This may not be the exact answer that you're looking for, but I hope this can guide you for a solution to your approach. I also found a [GraphQL sample](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/blob/master/packages/graphql_flutter/lib/src/widgets/query.dart) that uses [ObservableQuery](https://pub.dev/documentation/graphql/latest/internal/ObservableQuery-class.html) as a Stream that you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very complex and should be refactored. Please notice how dialogs must be called.

```dart
enum DialogResult {ok, cancel}
```

`caller_widget.dart`

```dart
FlatButton(
  child: Text('Open dialog'),
  onPressed: () async {
    // Call dialog and wait for result (async call)
    final dialogResult = await showDialog<DialogResult>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => DialogWidget(),
    );
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.ok) {
      // do something
    }
  },
),
```

`dialog_widget.dart`

```dart
...
FlatButton(
  child: Text('Ok'),
  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, DialogResult.ok), // DialogResult.ok returns
),
FlatButton(
  child: Text('Cancel'),
  OnPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, DialogResult.cancel), // DialogResult.cancel returns
),
```

So you *can* return required value *from* dialog and set it to required variable.

P.S. Try to avoid use of *old fashion* `then` process of futures and use `async/await`.